# How to check if a textbox is clicked on

Tags: javascript, css, if-statement, input, keyup

I have a keyup function on my script and when I type into one of my text boxes it triggers my hotkey which hides the text box so it makes it impossible to type in it. Please help.

```
$(document).keyup(function(e){
  if(e.which == 67){
       if($('#main').css('opacity') == 0) {
    $("#cHideChat").click();
      }
  }
});
```

I want something like this but I don't know the right word to put here.

```
$(document).keyup(function(e){
      if(e.which == 67){
       if($("#chat-input").is("clickedOn")){
         return false;
            }
       else{
         if($('#main').css('opacity') == 0) {
          $("#cHideChat").click();
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: StackOverflow has all the tools needed to create a [mcve] such as the CodeSnippet tool.

Comment: __unclear what you're asking__

Comment: i need to make it to where when i click on the chat input it disables my hotkey script

Comment: @SaladTato-Agario still unclear, what *is* your "hotkey" aand what's happening and what's your exact issue. Can you please put the minimal code to recreate your problem right into your question?

Comment: what does minimal script mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 67){
        if (e.target.id == "chat-input") {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
      if ($('#main').css('opacity') == 0) {
          $("#cHideChat").click();
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: im looking for a script that checks if i have clicked on the chat input. i know how to do that but i have no way to check if the chat input is in use.

Comment: i get an error saying that multiple parenthesis are missing

Comment: i got the same error but its ok because i think i just figured it out but i have to make a very over-complicated script.

Comment: Glad I could help to some extent!

Answer (score 2):

you can do it by checking the active element in jquery . The code should be like `$(document.activeElement).attr("type") == "text" || $(document.activeElement).attr("id") == "chat-input")`

Please let me know if it solves your problem

Comment: i dont what to do with this

Comment: then what you actually want ?

Comment: i meant to say i dont know what to do with this im so sorry that sounded really rude.

Comment: what do you mean by hotkey script ?

Comment: $(document).keyup(function(e){if(e.which == 67){
if($('#main').css('opacity') == 0) {
    $("#cHideChat").click();
      }
  }
});

Comment: the first script is the "hotkey" script. and i want to add a filter to check if the chat-input is being used.

Comment: can you provide some example .As 67 is ascii value for 'C'. so i am not able to get what are you trying to do.

Comment: this script makes it so that when i press c it checks if the menu has an opacity of 0 and if it does it clicks a checkbox option. i want to make a script that when i press c it checks if the menu has an opacity of 0 and if it does it checks to see if i clicked on the chat input and if i did nothing happens but if im not clicked on it it clicks the checkbox option.

Comment: hey i think you need to use `keypress` function instead of keyup

Comment: keyup works. the code works im just looking for something that checks if i clicked on the chat input. everything else works.

Comment: i dont know how to.